# Simple pagination for angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I need a simple pagination for Angular-in-memory-web-api. Right now I have:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';    

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {    
    createDb() {
        const comments = [
            {
                'user': 'User 1',
                'comment': 'Praesent ac ipsum mattis, consectetur leo sed, faucibus urna.'
            },
            {
                'user': 'User 2',
                'comment': 'Integer consectetur ex eu tincidunt laoreet.'
            },
            {
                'user': 'User 1',
                'comment': 'Curabitur et mi pretium, varius diam in, aliquet ante.'
            },
            {
                'user': 'User 2',
                'comment': 'Sed id quam sed est hendrerit malesuada sed accumsan eros.'
            },
            {
                'user': 'User 2',
                'comment': 'Vivamus iaculis est nec lorem maximus, sed euismod libero faucibus.'
            },
            {
                'user': 'User 1',
                'comment': 'Quisque placerat mauris vel ligula faucibus cursus.'
            },
            {
                'user': 'User 2',
                'comment': 'Nullam ultrices velit ut enim iaculis, ac pretium lorem dictum.'
            }
        ];

        return { comments };    
    }
}
```

I can access this with `('api/comments')`. I need a pagination like `('api/comments?per_page=5')` or something similar until the end of data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think angular-in-memory-web-api have this features.
You can create a service that do that, like:

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, skip, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

// the interface of your comments
import { IComment } from 'app/models';

@Injectable()
export class CommentsService{

    resourceUrl : string = 'api/comments';

    constructor(
        private http : HttpClient
    ){}

    getComments(params? : any) : Observable<IComment[]>{
        const {perPage, page} = params;
        return this.http.get<IComment[]>(this.resourceUrl).pipe(
            map((result : IComment[]) => {
                // you need to sort, if your data was not sorted
                return result.sort((a : IComment, b: IComment) => {
                    if(a.timestamp > b.timestamp) return 1;
                    if(a.timestamp < b.timestamp) return -1;
                    return 0;
                }).slice(perPage*page, perPage);
           })
        );
    }
}
```

it's only an idea.

Comment: Your example leaves the pagination in the service of the frontend. I think what @shrestha_aj is asking for is 'fake' backend behavior in the `InMemoryDbService`. Now CommentsService still gets all the comments, but what you typically want is prevent unneccesary requests and resonses from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you managed to solve this, but unfortunately angular-in-memory-web-api does not support pagination. You'll have to override the GET method yourself and do some tricks to get it working.

Here's my solution. It's a snippet of my `InMemoryDbService` implementation. My solution assumes that you use an `offset` and `limit` query parameter in the url, and return encapsulated data, with some meta information about the total count (so you know how many pages there are).

As you see, it contains quite some code. That's because I had to rewrite part of the logic that angular-in-memory-web-api normally handles for me, like filtering on other query parameters than `offset` and `limit`, etc. So I copied some of its internal code.

```js
  // HTTP GET interceptor to support offset and limit query parameters
  get(reqInfo: RequestInfo) {
    if (reqInfo.query.has('offset') && reqInfo.query.has('limit') && reqInfo.collection) {
      const offset = +reqInfo.query.get('offset')[0];
      const limit = +reqInfo.query.get('limit')[0];

      // Remove offset and limit from query parameters so they're not considered as filtering parameters for the
      // collection later on.
      reqInfo.query.delete('offset');
      reqInfo.query.delete('limit');

      return reqInfo.utils.createResponse$(() => {
        const collection = reqInfo.collection as Array<{id: any}>;

        let meta: any;
        let data: any;
        if (reqInfo.id) {
          data = reqInfo.utils.findById(collection, reqInfo.id);
        } else {
          const filteredCollection = InMemoryDataService.applyQuery(collection, reqInfo.query);
          const totalCount = filteredCollection.length;
          meta = { totalCount };
          console.log(`offset: ${offset}, limit: ${limit}`);
          data = filteredCollection.slice(offset, offset + limit);
          console.log(`Total count: ${totalCount}, and returned data count: ${data.length}`);
        }

        const options: ResponseOptions = data ?
        {
          body: { meta, data },
          status: STATUS.OK
        } :
        {
          body: { error: `'${reqInfo.collectionName}' with id='${reqInfo.id}' not found` },
          status: STATUS.NOT_FOUND
        };
        return InMemoryDataService.finishOptions(options, reqInfo);
      });
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  private static finishOptions(options: ResponseOptions, {headers, url}: RequestInfo) {
    options.statusText = getStatusText(options.status);
    options.headers = headers;
    options.url = url;

    return options;
  }

  private static applyQuery(collection: Array<object>, query: Map<string, string[]>) {
    // extract filtering conditions - {propertyName, RegExps) - from query/search parameters
    const conditions = [];
    query.forEach((values, key) => {
        values.forEach(value => { conditions.push({ key, rx: new RegExp(decodeURI(value), 'i') }); });
    });
    const len = conditions.length;
    if (!len) {
        return collection;
    }
    // AND the RegExp conditions
    return collection.filter(row => {
        let ok = true;
        let i = len;
        while (ok && i) {
            i -= 1;
            const cond = conditions[i];
            ok = cond.rx.test(row[cond.name]);
        }
        return ok;
    });
  }
```